# What type of bearing used in swivel arm?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

To model a swivel arm on column that rotates by hand 
What type of bearing should i use 
Should it support radial and axial load or just supporting axial load is enough ?

Comment: Use a bearing capable of supporting all the loads applied - first define those loads.

Comment: It probably needs to support some moments, as well as forces.

Comment: Ok can i use a pair of deep groove ball bearing and thrust ball bearing ?

Comment: What direction is the thrust?

Comment: Thrust direction is down cause i want to hang a 9kg mass from the end of the tube at the right .

Comment: Yes, you only want one thrust bearing not two, otherwise the way the down force is split between the two bearings will be unpredictable because it will depend on the tolerances of the assembly. Also, don't forget that the radial loads on the bearings will be much bigger than 9kgf, because of the moment created by the 9kg mass.

Answer (score 1):

you have both:
$$ M= 9kg*L+ lever\ weight*L/2$$

L = length of the lever arm.

$$ P = 9 + Lever\ weight $$

So you need a bearing that can carry both radial and axial.

Not any less important is to make sure the post and its attachment at base are strong enough to support sudden jerks and vibration of the start and stopping action of the lever.